# Список контактов пользователя

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Пытаюсь создать БД, используя EF (Code First). Хочу создать таблицу User (login,password), UserProfile (name,birth date,country), Contact (.....).

Необходимо выставить ключи таблиц так, чтобы пользователь имел список контактов. Какую связь установить между таблицами, при условии что пользователь должен иметь только один профайл, и пользователь может иметь много контактов (контакты - другие люди. аналогия со списком контактов в скайпе или ВК)? И как должен выглядеть инициализатор даной БД, а именно: как добавить конкретному пользователю определенный список контактов?

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Связь 1к1 плохая, лучше просто к User добавить поля.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы установить связи между таблицами, используя CodeFirst соглашение, будем использовать навигационные свойства. 
**1. Таблица User и Contact у вас иметь связь - один ко многим.** 
Соответственно, в одной таблице(в родительской) мы должны определить тип коллекции(таблица User), в дочерней - тип ссылки на родительскую(так называемое навигационное свойство)

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; } // указываем внешний ключ на таблицу User(передаем имя навигационного свойства)

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

2. **Таблица User и UserProfile имеют связь один к одному**.
    Соответственно, в обоих таблицах должны быть ссылку друг на друга, внесем изменения

   ```
   public class User
   {
      public int ID { get; set; }
      public string Login { get; set; }
      public string Password { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

      public virtual UserProfile Profile { get; set; }
   ```

   }

public class Contact
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

```
[ForeignKey("User")]
public int UserID { get; set; } // указываем внешний ключ на таблицу User(передаем имя навигационного свойства)

public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserID { get; set; } // указываем внешний ключ на таблицу User(передаем имя навигационного свойства)

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/data/jj713564.aspx). 
Теперь, имея данные классы, я думаю у вас не составит труда занести данные в БД. Просто работаете как с обычными классами. Для связи дочерней таблицы с родительской выставляется поле ID(поле, помеченной атрибутом `ForeignKey`) соответствующим значением первичного ключа родительской таблицы(таблицы User)

Comment: доступно обьяснили. а с точки зрения связей не стоит ли выставлять связь пользователь- контакты как многие ко многим? как будет правильнее сделать?

Comment: стоит не стоит - это решать вам, вы же архитектор вашей БД, нужна вам такая связь или нет. Связь многим ко многим реализуется как вы догадались - в обоих таблицах будет тип коллекции.